# Proper HTTP method for updating resource without affecting sub-resources in REST

Tags: web-services, api, rest

Let's assume I have two entities - project team and employee. Each employee could be part of multiple teams and each team can have multiple employees as team members. I need to provide REST API to manipulate teams, employees and relationships between them.

I have identified 3 resources - team, employee and member (association between team and employee), which is sub-resource of team. The reason I chosen to have member as sub-resource is purely based on lifecycle of this resource. Whenever team is removed members are removed as well as they don't have meaning outside of team itself.

I expose following API (relevant ones):

- `POST /teams` creates new team record with name, department ID, etc.
- `POST /teams/{name}/members` creates association between team identified by name and particular employee, so the input data contains employee ID

I also need to provide API to update department ID and other attributes of the team in one request. Looks like PUT is natural choice but semantics of PUT is pretty clear - I have to replace whole resource, which in this case means replacing all members sub-resources as well.

What method (or approach) should I use when I only want to update team's attributes while preserving member associations? Please keep in mind that I also want this request to be idempotent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Looks like PUT is natural choice but
>   semantics of PUT is pretty clear - I
>   have to replace whole resource, which
>   in this case means replacing all
>   members sub-resources as well.

I have never heard anyone make this association before.  If do `PUT /Foo`  in my opinion it says absolutely nothing about `/Foo/bar`.  Just because resource can be accessed through a hierarchal URI space does not infer any additional relations between those resources.

I have heard of people doing the opposite scenario where you do `PUT /Foo/bar` and if the server knows that this will impact the state of `/Foo` you can include a Content-Location header that points to `/Foo` to allow intelligent caches to invalidate `/Foo`.  However, the Content-Location is needed to explicitly create the relationship between the two resources.

Comment: this is very good point. I think you're right about me thinking about URI as a strict tree representation of set of resources. Instead I should think about them as just a way of identification where nesting means specification of namespace. Btw, if I go with this assumption how will GET response will look like for a "team"? Is it good thing to do to return URI's of members in the body or I should only return attributes of team and leave out members? Maybe including URI like "/teams/123/members" is a way to go?

Comment: @Oleg I would include a link to `/teams/123/members` in your team representation.

Comment: thanks, I need one more clarification, please, when doing PUT to `/teams/123` is it good idea to omit including link to `/teams/123/members` into body of request or this will confuse clients?

Comment: @Oleg  Elements of the representation that are not under the control of the client, such as the hypermedia links, can be safely omitted from the PUT request body.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should be using the PATCH method, but not sure which implementation uses it. If not, you should go the straight GET -> locally modify -> PUT cycle.

Also, depending on your design, you may interpret that sub-resources are not part of the resource itself. For instance, the contents of a team resource may contain a link to the list of resource members, say "`/team/{name}/members`", but not having the whole list as a contained element.

Comment: the problem is that using GET->modify->PUT will significantly complicate logic on the server. It will have to identify what associations have changed and perform back-end actions appropriately. I'd rather convey in the method and body the intent to update the team attributes only.

Comment: on the other hand not treating members as a separate resource might be the good idea. So if somebody wants to get list of members it will have to issue separate request while POST/PUT on 'teams' URI will always manipulate only team attributes

Answer (score -3):

I sort of think you're answering your own question.  `PUT` suggests the *creation* of a resource, with `POST` used for the update.

Another way of looking at this is that every change to a resource is really "creating a new version" of the resource.  every create, update and delete is adding a new version with new properties, and that *version* has its own, unique identifier.  When you `PUT` a new version of an existing resource, the old resource remains, so that the new resource can inherit from it.  Attempts to `PUT` a new version on an older version when a newer version of that resource already exists would return a redirect instead of a success, and so would some `GET` requests (ones that don't indicate that they are actually looking for an old version)